# Know number of threads running in apache beam direct runner

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-internals

I have an apache beam program in java running with direct runner. Apache beam uses threads in order to achieve distributed processing.

1. At run time how can I know the number of threads spawned by apache beam?
2. How can I set the maximum of number of threads to use at run time?

Answer (score 0):

This link below might be of help. In Java you seemingly can't as of 2021 Feb. In Python you can.

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/#parallel-execution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getTargetParallelism` and `setTargetParallelism` functions for this:

https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/runners/direct/DirectOptions.html